# Trim multiple items CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, trim

Have some base code I need modified to support the filtering of multiple items in the results field based on different strings.  For example I need to filter out everything that doesn't follow a pattern of "Version is 2.x.x.x.x" or " found" or any number of other combinations.

```
$FileIn  = '.\FileIn.Csv'
$FileOut = '.\FileOut.Csv'
$Keywords = '\sVersion is*', '\sFound\s'
Foreach($keyword in $keywords){
(Get-Content $FileIn) -replace $keyword,'' | Set-Content $FileOut }
```

Comment: Sorry but: what's your question?

Comment: Your question is imprecise. What exactly do you want to filter out? Just Use `Import-Csv myinputfile.csv | Where-Object { $_.Results -notmatch 'regexpattern' }`.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you have something you tried and it failed or did research into it or any kind of attempt....then this is the place for you. If you want someone to write code for you then you should hire a developer.

Comment: Updated the code.  I have tried serveral different versions/loops.  This is the closest I've gotten.  I can get the -replace to work outside of a for loop with just a single entry, however when I put it back in it fails to update the file.  I put a write-host in the for loop and can see that it was getting the $keywords separately.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.....I'm sure there is a cleaner version of my regular expressions but it works.

```
$Keywords = '\sVersion\sis\s.{2,16}', '\sfound', '\sshould.{2,40}','\sfile'
$Csv | ForEach-Object {
ForEach($keyword in $Keywords){
$_.Results = $_.Results -replace $keyword,''
 }}
$Csv | Export-Csv $FileOut -NoTypeInformation
```